# Spurious “This post has been edited” notice when improving a suggested edit

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, notifications, improve-edit

In the last weeks, the following happened to me a few times:

1. In the *suggested edits* queue, I choose to improve an edit.
2. I edit the post and submit the improved edit.
3. I receive a notice:

   > This post has been edited 2 times since you began. Your edit can only be saved if it is more thorough than the currently saved edit.

   However, there were only two recent edits to the post: the edit which I approved and my improvement to this edit.

I see no reason why this should be the intended behaviour and thus consider it a bug. As I cannot remember this happening before, I assume that it’s due to some recent change.

Comment: I thought I'd reported this myself before, but I can't find it now. It seems to be an intermittent problem.

Comment: Yeah, it used to happen to me too, but hasn't for quite some time.

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347844

Comment: [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/3073630)

Comment: Happened to me again this morning, so the bug is still out there.